# How to specify a selection event in a custom Spinner DropDownView?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a custom adapter to work with "Signal" objects.  It extends BaseAdapter and works fine when I customize a TextView and return it from the getDropDownView method of my Spinner.  However, I want to have a play/stop button in addition to the TextView label, so I extended LinearLayout to contain a TextView and ImageButton.  When I return the custom LinearLayout from getDropDownView instead of the plain TextView, it renders fine but the Spinner won't recognize any "selection" event.

When the getDropDownView method returns a TextView, clicking on the TextView appears to trigger a Spinner selection change without any coding help on my part.  I haven't been able to figure out what Android is doing to make that happen.  I want to define a Spinner selection change as a click on the TextView within my LinearLayout.  How can I go about doing that?  All of this is defined and manipulated in Java code, no xml.

Comment: BTW, I am targeting Android versions 2.x.  I know the Spinner has changed in later versions of Android, but don't know how those changes might affect this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to play a sound when the user clicks an item in your Spinner? I would use a OnItemSelectedListener():

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Log.v("Example", "Item Selected");
        // Play sound
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // Do nothing
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that onItemSelected will never get called.  That's the part I am trying to figure out.  Why will the dialog close and onItemSelected get called when I use a TextView but nothing at all occurs when I click on an extended LinearLayout?